# How to select * from any table and insert all those rows to another table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to select everything from table named : "felhasznalo_klan" and insert all those rows to another table named: "meccs_resztvevok"

I'm trying this code but it's just insert only first row from the "felhasznalo_klan" table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM felhasznalo_klan WHERE klannev='$klanod'";
$result = $kapcsolodas->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fnev = $row['fnev'];
        $query1 = "INSERT INTO meccs_resztvevok (matchid, fnev, csapat) VALUES ('$matchid', '$fnev', '1')";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($kapcsolodas,$query1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL statement to do this:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col1a, col2a, col3a, …)
  SELECT col1b, col2b, col3b, …
  FROM table_b;
```